# ACCESS iif Statement for Multiple conditoins

Tags: ms-access, iif-function

I'm trying to add multiple iif statements to one field in a query.  It is not working if I try to put it all together.  I don't know how to do this and make it work.  I've tried several different ways.

This is what I have:

IIf(([M1]='A')  OR ([M1]='J') OR ([M1]='S'), 1,0)

IIf(([M1]='B')  OR ([M1]='K') OR ([M1]='T'), 2,0)

IIf(([M1]='C')  OR ([M1]='L') OR ([M1]='U'), 3,0)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`Switch`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function. That takes an unlimited amount of parameters, and for the first odd-numbered parameter that's true, the even-numbered parameter after it gets returned.

```
Switch(([M1]='A') OR ([M1]='J') OR ([M1]='S'), 1,
   ([M1]='B') OR ([M1]='K') OR ([M1]='T'), 2
   ([M1]='C') OR ([M1]='L') OR ([M1]='U'), 3
   True, 0)
```